# positioning a column at the bottom of a row

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bourbon, neat

Hey guys i am using bourbon neat. I a in a dilemma here as i have to position the logo at the bottom of the page or probably 20% above bottom. 
i have this blue row that is spanning 3.5 columns of the full width container.
Now inside that row, i have inserted a logo  column and have it covered all 12 columns nested. 
**How can I take that logo column which is 12 column nested to bottom of the outer row.**

**Giving the logo row possition absolute or fixed breaks the row from out container and spreads the whole screen.**

[image]

here is my html Code

```
<body>
<div class="introContainer">

    <!-- Intro Deck -->
    <div class="introBar">

        <div class="introLogo">
            <img src="img/badge.png" height="156" width="156" alt="">

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

and heres is the generated css

```
  * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box; }

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; }
  body img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto; }

.introContainer {
  *zoom: 1;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background-image: url("../img/coverBg.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50%; }
  .introContainer:before, .introContainer:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table; }
  .introContainer:after {
    clear: both; }
  .introContainer .introBar {
    background-color: rgba(42, 196, 234, 0.9);
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 0%;
    width: 29.16667%;
    height: 100%; }
    .introContainer .introBar:last-child {
      margin-right: 0; }
  .introContainer .introLogo {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    border: 3px solid green;
    bottom: 22px; }
    .introContainer .introLogo:last-child {
      margin-right: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, the next time please use a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to show your code so it's easier for us to give you a quick answer.
Regarding to your question, try adding the css property **position: relative** to your **.introBar** css rule, so you'll have:

```
.introBar{
  position: relative;
}
```

then, you can position absolute your **.introLogo** regarding to **.introBar**.

```
.introLogo{
  bottom: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: thanks. Hey do tell me it possible to use a fiddle with a framework as i have to link all the external js and css right?

Comment: I think Jsfiddle is to show quick things, so you can do a "light" version of what you want to achieve with the least amount of code possible. Regarding to your question, yes, it has an option to link external resources (css, js) if you want.